# Tietze's Extension Theorem for unbounded function

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Tietze's Extension Theorem says that any continuous bounded real valued function from a closed set of a normal topological space $X$ can be extended to a continuous function on the space $X$. Is it still true if we remove the boundedness of the function from the hypothesis?

If not, is it true for the metric spaces if we remove the boundedness of the function from the hypothesis?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. Hint: Boundedness is not a topological property, namely you can "force" any real valued function to be bounded without losing topological properties.

Comment: Do you mean composing the map with a homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ to some open interval?

Comment: Yes, thats precisely it :)

Answer (score 2):

A proof sketch: a continuous map $f\colon A\to\mathbb R$ from a closed set $A\subseteq X$ can be seen as a continuous map $g\colon A\to(a,b)$ by considering a homeomorphism between $\mathbb R$ and an open interval $(a,b)$. Tietze's theorem for bounded functions only guarantees that there is a continuous extension $\tilde g\colon X\to[a,b]$ and some points may be sent to the boundary values $a,b$. We need to modify the function at these points properly so that it remains a continuous extension of $g$. The values $a,b$ does not come from the original domain, i.e. the preimage ${\tilde g}^{-1}(\{a,b\})$ is disjoint from $A$. Clearly, both $A$ and ${\tilde g}^{-1}(\{a,b\})$ is closed in $X$. So we can apply Urysohn's lemma.